# pst-eucl labels

Tags: pstricks

I just tried giving pst-eucl a spin, but I am struggling with the label positions. When trying the following example from the documentation

```
    \begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
        \pstTriangle[PointSymbol=square, PointSymbolC=o,
                     linecolor=blue, linewidth=1.5\pslinewidth]
                     (1.5,-1){A}(0,1){B}(-1,-.5){C}
    \end{pspicture}
```

All the labels seems to apear in (0,0), overlapping each other.

**UPDATE**
Marco's tips in the comments of his reply resolved the issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a small minimal example with the result -- everything works well.

I am using TeX Live 2011 and compiled with xelatex.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2.5,2)
\pstTriangle[PointSymbol=square, PointSymbolC=o,linecolor=blue, linewidth=1.5\pslinewidth](1.5,-1){A}(0,1){B}(-1,-.5){C}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

You can also compile as follows:

```
latex examplefile.tex
dvips examplefile.dvi
ps2pdf examplefile.ps
```

to get the pdf.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the example, but I suppose is my latex compiler thats the issue then. I'm using miktex and compiling your example gives me the exact same problem :/

Comment: @JustDanyul: Do you get any errors? How do you compile -- latex-ps-pdf?

Comment: I compile with "latex example.tex" and view the dvi with Yap. There is no compile errors

Comment: @JustDanyul: After that run `dvips example.dvi` and then run `ps2pdf example.ps`.

Comment: that worked! thanks alot! I'm curious though, how come it needs to be converted into pdf? and will this cause issues when including eps files? (I vaguely remember having issues with this before, it might have been using pdflatex though)

Comment: Only `ps2pdf` needs an explicitly-specified extension.